# How do I open pkl files with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a folder of pkl files in 'somefile' that I need to open as videos with opencv, but I keep getting the `_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow` error. What am I doing wrong? I know that my code isn't pretty... Please don't roast me lol

```
import cv2 import os import pickle import numpy as np

subdir ='somefile' files = os.listdir(subdir)

# open pkl filesfor f in files:
with open(subdir + '/' + f, 'rb') as infile:
    try:
        unpickled_videos = pickle.load(infile)
        for video in unpickled_videos:
            print('{} has been unpickled'.format(os.path.abspath(video)))
            # play video from file
            for video in unpickled_videos:
                if video == 'eye':
                    # create VideoCapture object, read from input file
                    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('eye' + '.mp4')

                    # check if camera opened successfully
                    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
                        print("Error opening {}".format(os.path.abspath(video)))

                    # convert resolutions from float to integer
                    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
                    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
                    fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)

                    # define codec and create VideoWriter object
                    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
                    out = cv2.VideoWriter(video + '.MP4', fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height), True)

                    # read until video is completed
                    while True:
                        # capture frame-by-frame
                        ret, frame = cap.read()

                        # display resulting frame
                        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                        # press Q on keyboard to exit
                        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('{} not found!'.format(f))
        pass
    except EOFError:
        print('End of file error')
        pass 

#when everything done, release video capture object and close all frames 
#cap.release() out.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load it as a numpy array with:

```
import numpy as np 
data = np.load(input_filename, allow_pickle=True)
```

The error sounds like it could be an issue with your data. In the case that some of your data is problematic, you could wrap the call in a try/except.

Comment: I edited my code to include what you had suggested above. My original error disappeared, but now I am receiving the error "OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "{'chapter': 2, 'eye': {'left': {'pos_x': array([ 440.26857574,  439.99729279,  440.28660381, ..., 1143.2058986..." (The full error is too long to include in this comment) The video file that I am trying to open is a movie scene with is overplayed with plots and eye tracking data, but it seems that opencv can't process the plots or eye tracking data. Do you have any leads?

Comment: I don't have enough information to make a very good recommendation. Looks like you were able to successfully unpickle the data.  It's looks like the data is JSON not a video data. The file contains tracking data separated by eye. Perhaps there is video data somewhere in that object as well. If not, do you have the original videos? You may need to write a script to plot the eye tracking data on top of the video data. Where did the data come from? Are you sure it's possible to watch these files as a movie?

Comment: The data is from my lab. I am unsure if it's possible to watch the unpickled files as a movie, but I also have the original video data, so I am now trying to plot the eye tracking data on top of the video files. What is the best way to get started on this script? Specifically, I am trying to track each eye with a circle, but I am struggling to move the circles according to the eye tracking data that I already have.